# How do you make AngularJS built-in services available globally?

Tags: angularjs

Code:

```
angular.module('appName').factory('serviceName', ['$http', function ($http) {
```

Here, I am making Angular's $http service available to my service but how do I make it available to all services in my app without having to define it every time in every service within the app (assuming every service in my app needs access to $http)?

There seems to be very little help on this issue.

Comment: but that's how dependency injection works

Comment: You don't define it, you inject it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
angular.module('appName').factory('globalize', ['$http', function ($http) {
    window.$http = $http;
}]);
```

e.g
http://plnkr.co/edit/HbyX2Bx8c3TNJyvL2ljf?p=preview

there you go, it's global now.  But this is not the best thing to do...

Comment: it won't work in newest versions of angular(if you never inject `globalize` somewhere) and defining something globally is the opposite idea of dependency injection.

Comment: Yes you have to inject it somewhere, no matter which angular you use.  With newer versions, you can use resolves to inject it. Like I said, it's not good practise, but that's how we solve the question.

Comment: and if you decided to use window to store it, this how you can do it without creating a service: `window.$http = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]')).injector().get('$http')` <- put this code `in app.run()`